# Сжатие фото на javascript

Tags: javascript

Как сжать фото и после отправить его на сервер?

Comment: В JS его нельзя сжать. Почему бы вам его не изменять в PHP файле?

Comment: @Yuri можно. Это костыльно, но можно.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, уточка, я хотел тебе давно сказать, ты меня бесишь :D

Comment: @Yuri, можно проследовать в чат и высказать мне все там а не в комментариях к рандомному вопросу) Почему бы не изменять в пхп файле? Очевидно чтобы не гонять все по сети. Про костыльное сжатие - я имею в виду вот это: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672746/how-to-compress-an-image-via-javascript-in-the-browser, переводить мне лень, смысл в том что изображение ресайзится для сжатия. Еще была оч хорошая статья на хабре по этому поводу с полгода назад, щас найду.

Comment: Вот классная статья, рассказывающая почему со сжатием изображений на ресайзе все оч плохо и как оно примерно работает: https://habrahabr.ru/post/252175/. Ей конечно куда больше чем полгода, полгода назад я ее прочитал)

Comment: Ну и да, в том что я написал выше под "сжатием" надо понимать "уменьшение веса изображения с допустимой потерей качества".